# Javascript add file input box button trouble

Tags: javascript, function, upload, element

I am building a multi file uploader and would like to start each input on a new line with a 
 with java script.

What I am trying to do is start every new box under each other instead of lining up next to each other. Could someone show me what to add to the java script so it creates an element 
.

I tried these adding them to the end of the javascript function, and it didnt work

```
var txt = document.createElement('br');
AND
txt = document.createElement('br');
AND
txt.element ="<br>";
```

i have a multi uploader here's the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title> :: FILEUPLOAD :: </title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div id="files">
      <input type="file" name="item_file[]">
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:_add_more();" title="Add more">+</a>
</form>

<script language="javascript">
<!--
function _add_more() {
    var txt = document.createElement('input');
    txt.type="file";
    txt.name="item_file[]";
    document.getElementById("files").appendChild(txt);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the assistance

Comment: Did you `appendChild` the `br` element?

Comment: You can either wrap each element in a div or add a css class containing display: block. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tdobxqLL/).

Comment: @ThiagoNegri Iv never heard of that, how would I use that for the box?

Comment: @ThiagoNegri, I used this     **txt.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));** but doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @BrianCherdak: add <style> input { display: block; } </style> in the head

Comment: @PiotrŁużecki that only works if these are the only inputs on the page or all inputs should be block.  Safer to add a class to the file inputs.

Comment: @PiotrŁużecki, it is, its like part uploader where you can add multiple files if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to each input:

```
function _add_more() {
  var txt = document.createElement('input');
  txt.type="file";
  txt.name="item_file[]";
  txt.className="file-picker";
  document.getElementById("files").appendChild(txt);
}
```

Then add display: block to your css for the class:

```
input.file-picker
{
  display: block
}
```

Working version in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tdobxqLL/1/).

EDIT: You may also want to add bottom padding to the CSS class.